# set a variable in outer apply statement sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to get one row in Outer apply statement for one of task Id, but SQL be angry me in outer apply statement with red line  :) Any ideas ?

```
declare @OwnerUserIDs as Nvarchar(max)

select bt.*
        ,cu.NAME+' '+cu.SURNAME as OwnerUserName
        ,cu2.NAME+' '+cu2.SURNAME as CreatedUserName
        ,T.Data
        from Business_Tasks(nolock) bt
        left join CommmerceCoreReleaseV1..CORE_USERS(nolock) cu on cu.USERID=bt.OwnerUserID
        left join CommmerceCoreReleaseV1..CORE_USERS(nolock) cu2 on cu2.USERID=bt.CreatedUserID
        outer apply 
         (                                      
             SELECT  @OwnerUserIDs = Data  from ( select COALESCE(@OwnerUserIDs + ';', '') + convert(nvarchar,bto.ownerUserID) as Data from Business_TasksOwner(nolock) bto where bto.TaskID=13) 
         ) T

        where bt.IsActive=1 and bt.ID=13
```

---

**Answer**
Hi, I found the answer, i changed inside of outer apply statement :

```
select bt.*
    ,cu.NAME+' '+cu.SURNAME as OwnerUserName
    ,cu2.NAME+' '+cu2.SURNAME as CreatedUserName
    ,T.OwnerUserIDs
    from Business_Tasks(nolock) bt
    left join CommmerceCoreReleaseV1..CORE_USERS(nolock) cu on cu.USERID=bt.OwnerUserID
    left join CommmerceCoreReleaseV1..CORE_USERS(nolock) cu2 on cu2.USERID=bt.CreatedUserID
    outer apply 
     (      

         select STUFF((SELECT ';'+ convert(nvarchar,bto.OwnerUserID) 
         FROM Business_TasksOwner(nolock) bto
         where bto.TaskID=bt.ID
         FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '') AS OwnerUserIDs
     ) T

    where bt.IsActive=1 and bt.ID=13
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, there are a few issues with your query as it stands:

- you need to add an alias name to your inner query, the one that starts "SELECT COALESCE...", i.e. put a letter, say X, after "bto.TaskId = 13)".
- you can't set your variable to the results of this sub-query the way you have, if you remove the "@OwnerUserIDs = " bit then your query should compile;
- I don't understand what your OUTER APPLY is trying to achieve, surely it will just return the same results for every row returned, i.e. where TaskId = 13?  Maybe this should be referring to the main query in some way?
- If you want to set the @OwnerUserIDs to be the concatenated results of the OwnerUserIDs then you need to use a different mechanism, either a recursive CTE or XML PATH query would work.

I would try to rewrite your query for you but I am not sure what you are trying to achieve here.  I guess you want to end up with a list of User Ids in @OwnerUserIDs but I'm not sure what the rules should be...

Comment: You're right in the first statement.

This is a spesific query, if i solve this compile problem, i'll generalize my query; therefore the Id is 13.

Comment: Great, so XML PATH was the answer then... :D